# Update pagination in AngularJS after filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I already have the pagination implemented.
Now I want the pagination to be updated after filtering my results.

The form:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="search.name" data-ng-change="filter()"/>
```

The list:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search) | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">{{data.name}}</li>
```

The pagination:

```
<pagination data-boundary-links="true" data-num-pages="noOfPages" data-current-page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize"></pagination>
```

The controller:

```
$scope.filter = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() { //wait for 'filtered' to be changed
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length/$scope.entryLimit);
        $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };
    }, 10);
};
```

My problem is, the pagination is just updated after clicking on a page number or after entering the next character into the input field. So it is update one step to late.

**EDIT**: I added the source to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eqCWL/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$timeout` instead of `window.setTimeOut`. `$timeout` is wrapped properly to work consistently in Angular.

Answer (score 36):

@abject_error 's answer using `$timeout` does work. I edited your fiddle with his suggestion and made this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nackjicholson/5p6vF/2/)

**CAVEAT**

I think the solution is indicative of a bigger problem in the form of a race condition!

## [jsFiddle using filterFilter and $watch](http://jsfiddle.net/nackjicholson/5p6vF/)

and that fiddle is the way around it for reals.

**And here is the explanation**

Your race condition is between handling the change of `search` and the availability of `$scope.filtered`.

I think the culprits to eliminate in order to resolve this race condition are:

```
ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()"
```

and

```
ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search)......."
```

Using `ng-change` to fire off "filter()" to do the calculation of `noOfPages` but also depending on a change in search in order to create `filtered`. Doing it this way, ensures the filtered list cannot possibly be ready in time to calculate the number of pages, and that's why hobbling "filter()" by 10ms with a timeout gives you the illusion of a working program.

What you need is a way to "watch" `search` for changes, and then filter the list in a place where you have access to both creating `$scope.filtered` and calculating `$scope.noOfPages`. All in sequence, without a race.

Angular has that way! It is possible to use the `filter` filter in your controller as function very poorly named: `filterFilter`. Check this out in the [Filters Guide - Using filters in controllers and services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Inject it into the controller.

```
function pageCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
    // ...
}
```

Use it in a `$watch` function, documented in the [scopes docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(term) {  
    // Create filtered 
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.list, term);  

    // Then calculate noOfPages
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length/$scope.entryLimit);  
})
```

Change the template to reflect our new way. No more in DOM filter, or `ng-change`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search"/>
```

and

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
    {{data.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: This looks like a better sollution but if i change the ng-model="search" to ng-model"search.name" as follow <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Search"/> it seems to break. What is causing this. I am asking this because i would like to be able to filter on multiple columns

Comment: Change the watch expression to `search.name` as well. You may want to consider if $watchCollection is something to use in your case. Allows you to watch the properties of an object.

Comment: I had already figured out the third parameter of the $watch function but i think the $watchCollection is even better. Thanks for that.

Comment: I have my own pagination directive as I have to implement pagination and searching across multiple pages. In this case, how can i add the searching logic to my directive as ng-repeat refers to the controller. If i have to add this logic to the controller, then i have to copy paste the code for all of my pages. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am in the same boat... I love this solution, but I am not sure how to implement it across my entire application without copy/pasting the code in every single controller

Comment: @MattHintzke You might want to check this: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Comment: Guys, <pagination> tag doesn't appear on my page. even  thought ui-bootstrap is injected. Can enyone give me a hint?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where the filter filterFilter is defined. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use this directive instead:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

It offers pagination with a filter while keeping the code nice and clean.

Kudos to michaelbromley for the great code.

Answer (score 2):

Use angular `$scope.$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(term) {
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length/$scope.entryLimit);
    }
});
```

Source ; http://jsfiddle.net/eqCWL/2/

Demo ; http://jsfiddle.net/eqCWL/192/