# Custom filter in AngularJS after adding pagination

Tags: javascript, filter, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

After implementing the pagination to my ng-repeat listing ([Update pagination in AngularJS after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144017/update-pagination-in-angularjs-after-filtering))

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search) ... >
```

I now have a problem with my custom filter

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search) | customFilter:search ... >
```

I need this filter to search by multiple languages (select two or more languages).
If I you replace **data in filtered = (list | filter:search)** with **data in list**, you will see it's working. But I need **filtered** for my pagination.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/StinsonMaster/SuEX6/4/ (based on [the fiddle from the previous thread](http://jsfiddle.net/eqCWL/2/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misunderstood your original question.

I rewrote your custom filter. It's not exactly objected oriented, but with a little touching up it could be much more extensible. Basically you just needed something that was more inclusive than the base angular filter.

```
app.filter("customFilter", function() {
    return function(input, search) {
        if(search && search != undefined) {
            var _toRet = new Array();
            for(var i in search) {
                for(var k in input) {
                    if(search.indexOf(input[k].language) != -1 && _toRet.indexOf(input[k]) == -1) {
                        _toRet.push(input[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return _toRet;
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    };
});
```

Also please note the changes to your ngRepeat syntax.

```
ng-repeat="data in filtered = list | filter:search.name | customFilter:search.language | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doublekid/5Bs3h/

Comment: Looks promising. Here is an updated fiddle with valid js references (the original was producing an error). http://jsfiddle.net/YaQK2/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, instead of using an expression in your ng-repeat directive, set the ng-repeat equal to a method on the list's constroller that returns the subset or values you're looking for. For example:

```
// In your controller

        $scope.filteredList = function() {
           return $filter('filter')($scope.list,{'language':search.language});
        }

// And in your ng-repeat 

        ng-repeat="(key,val) in filteredList()"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm, okay... Can you fork my fiddle? I tried your code but didn't figure out how to use it.